# Substract series from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

So I have a class(with header):

```
df1=             
         value
 B     0.000367
 S     0.000486
 T     0.000259
 J     0.000177
```

and a series (without header):

```
ser1=
 B    0.021711
 S    0.023538
 T    0.017815
 L    0.013303
```

I am looking forward to substract series from dataframe. I first try to substract them directly obtaining:

```
           B         L        T       S    value  
B         NaN        NaN     NaN     NaN   NaN
S         NaN        NaN     NaN     NaN   NaN
T         NaN        NaN     NaN     NaN   NaN
L         NaN        NaN     NaN     NaN   NaN
```

Then i tried to convert the series to df by:

```
ser1.to_frame
```

Then I repeated the process and this error appears:

dtype: float64> with block values unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'method' and 'float'

I simply want to make a substraction df1-ser1

Comment: it's `ser1.to_frame()` with the parentheses. Otherwise, you are subtracting a method from a dataframe, which is why you're getting that error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.sub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sub.html):

```
df = df1.sub(ser1, axis=0)
print (df)
      value
B -0.021344
J       NaN
L       NaN
S -0.023052
T -0.017556
```

Also is possible convert `Series` to `DataFrame` by [`Series.to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_frame.html):

```
df = df1.sub(ser1.to_frame('value'))
print (df)
      value
B -0.021344
J       NaN
L       NaN
S -0.023052
T -0.017556
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also keep what you have so far by adding parentheses to the `.to_frame` method and providing a column name matching the dataframe's column name:

```
df1 - ser1.to_frame('value')

#       value
# B -0.021344
# J       NaN
# L       NaN
# S -0.023052
# T -0.017556
```

I hope this helps.